# setClickListener from runnable not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-runonuithread

I am working on an Android application that downloads images from a server and displays them in a Recycler view.
I am having issues enabling the onclick for each of the images.

In my **MyRecyclerViewAdapterClass**:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView myTextView;
    public ImageView myImage;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        myImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_test);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    String getItem(int id){
        return mData[id];
    }
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position){
        Log.i("TAG","You clicked number" + getItem(position));
}
```

In my **main activity**:

```
public void postImage() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //RecyclerView.
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, numberOfColumns));
            MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context,data,file_payload);

            **adapter.setClickListener(this);**
            adapter.mData = data;
            adapter.PAYLOADS = allPayloads;
            adapter.DATES = allDates;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });}
```

When I call adapter.setListener(this) I get an error:

> setClickListener in my RecyclerView cannot be applied,
>   anonymous.java.lang.Runnable

I have tried creating a itemClickListener in the runnable as you can see in the code, using that for the call adaptersetClickListener(itemClickListener), however I get an error because itemClickListener is not initialised.

If I do not call the setClickListener method, the mClickListener is never set and is always null. When debugging, I noticed the click is registered but nothing happens because mClickListener is null.

Comment: In that scope, `this` is the `Runnable`. If you want `MainActivity`, use `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I call adapter.setListener(this) I get an error:

Because  here `this` indicate a `Runnable` instance you implemented and you are passing a `Runnable` instance not  `MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener` in adapter.

I think you are trying to pass a `MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener` instance to `ViewHolder`. If i am correct,

For that:

1. You have to implement `MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener` in MainActivity
2. Pass that instance to `Adapter`.
3. And from `Adapter` pass that instance to `ViewHolder`.

**In MainActivity:**

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener listener = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
     Log.i("TAG","You clicked number" + position);
  }
};

adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context,data,file_payload);
adapter. setItemClickListener( listener);
```

**In Adapter**

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
 }

ItemClickListener listener;

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}

@Override 
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder =  new ViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.setItemClickListener(listener);
    return viewHolder;
 }
```

**In your ViewHolder:**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
public TextView myTextView;
public ImageView myImage;
MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    myImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_test);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (itemClickListener != null) itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
 }


void setItemClickListener(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
 }


  String getItem(int id){
    return mData[id];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I go about implementing ItemClickListener in my MainActivity?